# How to route all images from views and css to use IMGIX url in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, image, amazon-s3, webpack, imgix

so I have a laravel project, which is nearly finished and we just transferred all images to the S3 bucket and connected an IMGIX to the S3 buckets so all images are served from the S3 through IMGIX which also enables to do all sorts of customizations on the flight.

However, the images in the CSS are with relative paths, for an example

```
.bg-image {
   background: url(/storage/icons/icon.svg);
}
```

And the images in the views, are like this:

```
<img class="icon" src="{{ asset('storage/icons/icon-white.svg') }}" />
```

Is there any way I can dynamically add IMGIX url ([www.domain.imgix.net](http://www.domain.imgix.net)) in front of all images on the site (views + CSS) so they all go through the IMGIX?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset), you can configure the asset URL host by setting the `ASSET_URL` variable in your project `.env` file. For example:

```
ASSET_URL=https://www.domain.imgix.net
```

For a more complicated use case, you might want to consider creating a helper method that extends asset and uses the imgix-php [client library](https://github.com/imgix/imgix-php).

Comment: Yes, I tried it, however, the ASSET_URL will route all assets through that URL, including CSS, JS....

Answer (score 0):

try to edit the routes/web.php

add the following

```
Route::get('/images/{filename}', function ($filename) {
if (env(    'FILESYSTEM_DRIVER') === 's3') {
    $s3BucketUrl = env('MIX_S3_URL'); // Replace with your S3 bucket URL
    $s3ObjectUrl = $s3BucketUrl . '/images/' . $filename;
    return Redirect::to($s3ObjectUrl);
}
})->where('filename', '.*');
```